# if else condition in commandlink value

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
<apex:commandLink value="ADD" onclick="return divToggle('{!oplist.lineNumber}');"/>
```

I want to apply if else condition ,if UnitPrice is not null then View commandlink should show otherwise Add should show..

Comment: If the links have the same action, <apex:commandLink value="{!If(oplist.UnitPrice <> null, 'VIEW', 'ADD')}" onclick="return divToggle('{!oplist.lineNumber}');"/> if actions are different then two different links as rao has proposed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I follow you right you need to display a command link when unitprice is not null. If thats the case try

updated:

```
<apex:page standardController="account">
<apex:form >
<apex:commandLink value="ADD" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(account.name))}"/>
<apex:commandLink value="View command link" rendered="{!(ISNULL(account.name))}"/>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

replace the account.name with your unitprice

rendered attribute allows you to control the visibility conditionally on a command link

Comment: but i also need to show View command link..based on this...

Comment: thanks for replying...actually its showing an error...Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 1

Comment: I have updated the code check it out!! Hope this helps